# How can I add unique url for coupon in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

So I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtawKH6VlQY) but what I want to do is a bit different.

I want to have a unique link per coupon generator and the coupon is per customer and can only be used once (e.g. `example.com/coupon/7AD8679adO`).

Now I want to have a form for this page and just have a input boxes for users like `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email`. And the `email` field is the identifier that the current url coupon will be registered to that email.

I also tried to research and I found out that there's URL Coupons feature from `Woocommerce` (Not sure though if this is exactly what Im looking for), but suddenly, it is not free. So, any idea with this?

Comment: Not a full answer, but look into the [Wordpress Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

Comment: @Slbox Okay, but how about on the client side? How do they visit the generated url?

Comment: I think you're likely to have to create custom code to integrate WooCommerce with any redirection solution unless you find a pre-built solution tailored just for WooCommerce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented rewrite rule in "twentytwentyone" theme, but **you may implement it elsewhere in wordpress**.

For more info, please refer to this.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/

#### Implement in wordpress Theme

1. Add the following code to the bottom of next file

~/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/**functions.php**

```
// wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/functions.php
...
// rewrite-rule
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'coupon/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?coupon=$matches[1]', 'top' );
} );

// whitelist "coupon" param
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'coupon';
    return $query_vars;
} );

// set template php file
add_action( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    if ( get_query_var( 'coupon' ) == false || get_query_var( 'coupon' ) == '' ) {
        return $template;
    }
    
    //You can return wherever you want to go
    return get_template_directory() . '/template-coupon.php';
} );
```

2. Create ~/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/**template-coupon.php**

```
// wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/template-coupon.php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    echo get_query_var( 'coupon' )." from POST".PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($_POST);

    // check coupon validation here
    // $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT 1"); // Your query
    // $result = $wpdb->get_var($query);
    // var_dump($result);


} else  {
    echo get_query_var( 'coupon' )." from redirection GET".PHP_EOL;
    // do something
}

?>


<?php //get_template_part( 'header' ); ?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"><br/>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"><br/>
    <label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php //get_template_part( 'footer' ); ?>
```

#### Implement in wordpress Plugin (Hello Dolly)

1. Add the above step 1 code to the bottom of next file

~/wp-content/plugins/**hello.php**

change

```
return get_template_directory() . '/template-coupon.php';
```

to

```
return __DIR__ . '/template-coupon.php';
```

2. Add the above step 2 code to ~/wp-content/plugins/**template-coupon.php**

#### Refresh permalinks cache

When you add/modify URL part in step1, you need to refresh permalniks cache, otherwise wordress does not apply rewrite rule.

> Settings > Permalinks > Save Changes
> [image]

#### Result

check http://your-domain/coupon/7AD8679adO/
[image]

Comment: Okay, so how can I view the generated url coupon (or coupon code)? And how do we save it in the database? sorry Im new in plugin development

Comment: If you would like to use existing theme, you may use something like get_template_part('header'), I will update my code above.

Comment: @Jonjie , you can use any wordpress object or variable like **$wpdb** in template-coupon.php. Also, you may implement **add_rewrite_rule** in your plugin.

Comment: Okay so how can I generate new coupon? which part of the page? and where this coupon would save?

Comment: Okay, now I get the idea. Please just add more explanation for future developers.

Comment: @Jonjie , I assume that you have some experienece in PHP and Wordpress. You would have coupon records in DB if you use any coupon plugin. Then, you can use the above code as URL redirection or hook to somewhere(php code in plugin or template) you want to go with coupon code param. Hope this make sense to you.

Comment: What if I want to do it on my plugin instead of inside the theme?

Comment: @Jonjie , Please check the above answer, I added plugin part as well.

Comment: Im having problem with caching (I think). When I try to echo the data from a query in the page like `status: 1`, then update the `status` column in the database to `2`, and when I visit the page again, the `status` is still `1` instead of `2`. Any idea?

Comment: @Jonjie , if it is browser cache issue, you can check the issue URL with private /incognito mode in your browser. Otherwise, you need to find out where the cache is, for example, DB layer, WP application layer etc. If you can not sort it out, please create another question with your enviornment like OS, WP version, PHP version and PHP extension, DB info and minimal reproducible code.

Comment: All good now. The problem was my production has plugin installed called WP Rockets that’s why it’s always caching the data/page.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you've seen this answer elsewhere, but I hope this is written clearly enough for you to understand it better.

It seems as though you may need to implement the "add_rewrite_rule()" in order for WordPress to recognise the element (the unique "/coupon/URL") and pass on the resulting code to the right page.

---

Additionally, it can sometimes be a bit more difficult to verify a coupon code without the user being logged into an account that can be relied on.
Therefore, I would recommend trying to store the uniquely generated "/coupon/URL" in the user's meta data, and then querying for the unique in the user's meta data, and validating the request if the current user and the related user's ID match. This is because the code doesn't just get tied to the email address, but also to a registered user.